# Play! 2.1 want me to write scala code

Tags: java, scala, playframework, playframework-2.1

I hope it's the last errors I will encounter migrating to Play! 2.1.

All my controllers returns throw an error using `compile` command.

```
return ok(createOrUpdate.render(Secured.getConnectedUser(), getCustomers(), User.build(user)));

[error]   required: User,scala.collection.immutable.List<User>,User
[error]   found: User,java.util.List<User>,<null>
```

I don't understand why play! 2.1 want me to use scala api instead of java api.

Here is my `build.scala` file :

```
import sbt._
import Keys._
import PlayProject._

object ApplicationBuild extends Build {

    val appName         = "webapp-stativiz"
    val appVersion      = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

    val appDependencies = Seq(
      javaCore,
      javaJdbc,
      javaEbean,
      "org.mongodb" % "mongo-java-driver" % "2.10.1",
      "pdf" % "pdf_2.9.1" % "0.3",
      "commons-io" % "commons-io" % "1.3.2",
      "commons-codec" % "commons-codec" % "1.7"
    )

    val main = play.Project(appName, appVersion, appDependencies, mainLang = JAVA).settings(
          resolvers += Resolver.url("My GitHub Play Repository", url("http://www.joergviola.de/releases/"))(Resolver.ivyStylePatterns) 
    )

}
```

**EDIT :**

Using `run` command I have this exception :

```
sbt.PlayExceptions$CompilationException: Compilation error[error: method render in class createOrUpdate cannot be applied to given types;]
        at sbt.PlayReloader$$anon$2$$anonfun$reload$2$$anonfun$apply$15$$anonfun$apply$16.apply(PlayReloader.scala:349) ~[na:na]
        at sbt.PlayReloader$$anon$2$$anonfun$reload$2$$anonfun$apply$15$$anonfun$apply$16.apply(PlayReloader.scala:349) ~[na:na]
        at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:133) ~[scala-library.jar:na]
        at sbt.PlayReloader$$anon$2$$anonfun$reload$2$$anonfun$apply$15.apply(PlayReloader.scala:349) ~[na:na]
        at sbt.PlayReloader$$anon$2$$anonfun$reload$2$$anonfun$apply$15.apply(PlayReloader.scala:346) ~[na:na]
        at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:133) ~[scala-library.jar:na]
```

**SOLUTION :**

Delete your project. Create a new one.

Comment: It seems the import should be `import play.Project._`

Comment: checked too. same problem

Answer (score 1):

`mainLang = JAVA` is no longer required in Play! 2.1: the dependencies `java*` are enough for Play! to identify your main application language.

The rest of your file seems correct. Try run `play clean clean-all compile` to make it work.

Comment: I know. I've tried with and without mainLang parameter. I've launched play clean clean-files compile. clean-all is not a valid command on my CLI

Comment: Sorry, I meant "clean-files".

Answer (score 1):

scala  should handle the type conversion from java list to scala list. 
So I think you may be looking at the list type instead of the null where expects type user.
Is the last field in the below statement returning null?

```
return ok(createOrUpdate.render(Secured.getConnectedUser(), getCustomers(), User.build(user)));

[error]   required: User,scala.collection.immutable.List<User>,User
[error]   found: User,java.util.List<User>,<null>
```

Comment: Yes the last field is null and it's an expected behaviour. As I said all my controllers have this problem. The problem is that scala doesn't handle the type conversion.

Comment: Strange you're seeing the error still - Scala has a java type converter that will convert types if included. See here: http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.JavaConverters$

Answer (score 0):

The solution is :

1. Create a new project
2. Put your files inside (app, public... folders)
3. Delete your old project

So... is that called a migration ? Play! 2.1 is worst release I've seen :(

Comment: After that, you should make a diff of the two projects to see what is different: I am really interested. I migrated several apps from Play! 2.0 to Play! 2.1 and the only issues I got were my mistake (did not read enough carefully the documentation). But I admit there may be bugs (Play! 2.1 still seems a bit buggy).

Comment: easy to give me -1. Nobody find an answer there. That's not the first problem I encounter with Play! 2.1 and yes I've checked differences : /project/project/target and /project/target are completely different compared to a play! 2.0 app. So it's impossible to fix manually. As I said it's more efficient to create a new project than editing 3 files and launching 3 commands IMHO

Comment: *project/project/target* and *project/target* are not interesting for this comparison: they can be cleared and re-genereted (you may event delete them manually). The interesting part would be (I guess) somewhere around *project* folder.